# java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Sqoop)

Tags: networking, server, java, mysql

I am new to sqoop. I am trying to import the data from mysql(installed in windows)using sqoop but i am getting below error.

7/08/11 22:55:49 ERROR manager.SqlManager: **Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 33 more
17/08/11 22:55:49 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Kindly Advice.